# Trouble with saving data on MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to save the data obtained by the serial port from Arduino to MySQL database, but I can only save once since I have to run the program again to save once more, I tried to use a while loop but I persist on the database only once and keep getting the "Failed to get data from Arduino!".

Here's my code:

```
import serial
import MySQLdb


dbConn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","sasa","sms") or die ("could not connect to database")
cursor = dbConn.cursor()

device = 'COM3'

try:
  print "Trying...",device
  arduino = serial.Serial(device, 9600)
except:
  print "Failed to connect on",device


try:
  data = arduino.readline()
  pieces = data.split("\t")

  try:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO industrial (db) VALUES (%s)", (pieces[0]))
    dbConn.commit()
    cursor.close()
  except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    print "failed to insert data"
  finally:
    cursor.close()
except:
  print "Failed to get data from Arduino!"
```

Comment: what is the purpose of it ? is arduino constantly pushing data and you need to read it all the time ? There are a few ways to achieve this.

Comment: I'm trying to get the value from a sound sensor, and put the data received into database, and yes, it has to be all the time, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it, it was really simple actually, i just put a `while True:` at the beginning, and it was updating correctly, here's the code if anyone is interested:

```
import serial
import MySQLdb

while True:
    dbConn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","sasa","sms") or die ("could not connect to database")
    cursor = dbConn.cursor()

    device = 'COM3'


    try:
      print "Trying...",device
      arduino = serial.Serial(device, 9600)
    except:
      print "Failed to connect on",device


    try:
      data = arduino.readline()
      pieces = data.split("\t")


      try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO industrial (db) VALUES (%s)", pieces)
        dbConn.commit()
        cursor.close()
      except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
        print "failed to insert data"
      finally:
        cursor.close()
    except:
      print "Failed to get data from Arduino!"
```